# How to block uploading files in a webpage in Internet explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Are there any options in Interment explorer to block the file uploading ?

I just want to have a scenario where the file upload fail due to Internet explorer setting or due to my desktop settings .

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want this? More detail would be useful :)

Comment: Hi Im just creating a document on how to resolve this kind of scenario so that help desk can actually resolve this issue instead of lodging case and assign to the technical people .

Comment: Why don't you wait for a real case with this issue, solve it and then document it?